# Union of two temporary tables

Tags: mysql, union, temp-tables

I have a temporary table `a`

```
"date"          "value"
"2016-09-09"    0.0533
"2016-09-12"    0.0552
"2016-09-14"    0.0567
"2016-09-15"    0.0537
"2016-09-19"    0.0529
"2016-09-19"    0.0506
"2016-09-19"    0.0525
"2016-09-20"    0.0517
"2016-09-20"    0.0534
```

and a temporary table `b` that gives me a weekly average every Saturday

```
"date"          "avgValue"
"2016-09-10"    0.0533
"2016-09-17"    0.0552
"2016-09-24"    0.0522
```

The dates almost never line up, but may on occasion. I want to do a full outer join, but mysql does not allow it. So I’ve been trying all kinds of unions and joins, and the problem has been kicking my butt for the last 4 hours. The table I want looks like this

```
"date"          "value"    "avgValue"
"2016-09-09"    0.0533      NULL
"2016-09-10"    NULL        0.0533
"2016-09-12"    0.0552      NULL
"2016-09-14"    0.0567      NULL
"2016-09-15"    0.0537      NULL
"2016-09-17"    NULL        0.0552
"2016-09-19"    0.0529      NULL
"2016-09-19"    0.0506      NULL
"2016-09-19"    0.0525      NULL
"2016-09-20"    0.0517      NULL
"2016-09-20"    0.0534      NULL
"2016-09-24"    NULL        0.0522
```

So far I have this which does nothing.

```
select *
from a
left join b
on b.date = a.date
union
select *
from a
right join b
on b.date = a.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `union all`/`group by` approach:

```
select date, max(value) as value, max(argvalue) as argvalue
from ((select date, value asvalue, NULL as argvalue from a) union all
      (select date, NULL, argvalue from b)
     ) ab
group by date;
```

Comment: Judging from his desired output, you don't need the outer portion of that query.

Comment: You sir, are a saint. Its taken me 4 hours and you solved the problem almost immediately. You missed a space between 'as' and 'value' and put argvalue instead of avgvalue, but once I corrected that, immediately worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JaredPeterson - Gordon is the master. :)

Comment: @MontyPython I think youre right. Hes literally written the book. Well, 4 books. *swoon*